# The provided definition does not specify a valid version field when render openapi

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openui

I am integrate the OpenAPI with my project, when I access the url: `http://127.0.0.1:11014/swagger-ui/index.html`, shows error like this:

```
Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).
```

this is the OpenAPI config:

```
package misc.config.openapi;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.ExternalDocumentation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.License;
import org.springdoc.core.GroupedOpenApi;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * https://springdoc.org/
 * https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi
 */
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi fortuneApi() {
        GroupedOpenApi.Builder builder = GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .pathsToMatch("/fortune/**")
                .group("dddd");
        GroupedOpenApi groupedOpenApi = builder.build();
        return groupedOpenApi;
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI fortuneAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("Fortune API")
                        .description("Spring shop sample application")
                        .version("v0.0.1")
                        .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")))
                .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation()
                        .description("SpringShop Wiki Documentation")
                        .url("https://springshop.wiki.github.org/docs"));
    }

}
```

I have read the question [Swagger..Unable to render this definition The provided definition does not specify a valid version field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951641/swagger-unable-to-render-this-definition-the-provided-definition-does-not-speci) and tried the answer, both did not work. what should I do to specify the version? This is the dependencies looks like:

```
    api "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9"
```

I make a minimal reproduce and found the normal response is json object, but the problem response return string. This is the correct response:

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "Fortune API",
        "description": "Spring shop sample application",
        "license": {
            "name": "Apache 2.0",
            "url": "http://springdoc.org"
        },
        "version": "v0.0.1"
    },
    "externalDocs": {
        "description": "SpringShop Wiki Documentation",
        "url": "https://springshop.wiki.github.org/docs"
    },
    "servers": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:11018",
            "description": "Generated server url"
        }
    ],
    "paths": {},
    "components": {}
}
```

this is the problem response in my project:

```
"{\"openapi\":\"3.0.1\",\"info\":{\"title\":\"Fortune API\",\"description\":\"Spri......
```

Answer (score 12):

Finally I found that I changed the json converter cause this problem, this is a solved way:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConvertConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

this `StringHttpMessageConverter` should be the first one added into converter. I think this is the openapi design problem to make it hard to use. More information from here:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/624
- [Endpoint "/api-docs" doesn't work with custom GsonHttpMessageConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393191/endpoint-api-docs-doesnt-work-with-custom-gsonhttpmessageconverter)
- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/683
- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1826
- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/900

Comment: after many hours of searching I found your response as valid, nice, and hard to find in the haystack. thank you

Comment: I actually had this Converter in place to solve date serialization in Rest endpoints. This Converter broke OpenApi.                                                                            
Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.x.y (for example, openapi: 3.1.0).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same thing but for a different reason. The endpoint `v3/api-docs` return a base64 string instead of json. (Something like: `eyJvcGVuYXBpIjoiMy4wLjEiLCJpbmZvIjp7InRpdGxlIjoiT3BlbkFQSSBkZWZpbml0aW9uIiwid..`).

After searching a bit, i found that when overriding the default spring-boot registered `HttpMessageConverter`, you should have ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter registered as well to have proper springdoc-openapi support.

```
        converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(jacksonBuilder.build()));
```

Note: **Order is very important, when registering HttpMessageConverters.**

References:

- https://springdoc.org/#why-am-i-getting-an-error-swagger-ui-unable-to-render-definition-when-overriding-the-default-spring-registered-httpmessageconverter
- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/2143